# Ajax request is not working with ASP.NET page method

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, pagemethods

I tried so many example codes and neither works. Ajax call simply does not return anything. There is no alert popup.

This is the ajax code :

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({         
            type: "POST",
            url: "mysqlcall.aspx/Testing",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: {""},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("idkbro");
                //  $("#testing").text(response.d);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And this is the call page :

```
public partial class mysqlcall : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
    }

    public string Testing()
    {
        return "asdlasldalsdl";
    }
}
```

I'm running it on latest version of IIS and using asp.net C# webforms with routing. mysqlcall.aspx is not routed but it doesn't matter I tried it with a routed page. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit : Thanks to @wazz the problem was in the

```
url: "mysqlcall.aspx/Testing",
```

instead it has to begin with a slash like :

```
url: "/mysqlcall.aspx/Testing",
```

Comment: Start debugging: put a breakpoint in Testing(), does it get called?

Comment: Side note: don't start a new project with asp.net webforms. Make sure you know about MVC and SPA.

Comment: And I'm a bit doubtfull about `type: "POST"`, isn't this a GET ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Can't put breakpoints since im deplyoing the website to the remote server , cant be runned on localhost.
It's too late for me to start MVC projects , for the past few months ive been learning Webforms and i really dont have the time at the moment.
Tried with "GET" , same thing.

Comment: "cant be runned on localhost" - In VS, go to File|New|Project, create a simple testproject. You will need it a lot to test things like this. Keep it simple. Your code is already close to a mcve, make it work. See [mcve]

Comment: @HenkHolterman the url works , if i do for example just     $(document).ready(function () { $.ajax({ alert('test');}); the alert popups,Also the mysqlcall.aspx is working.
I i'll try to create a new projects now on the localhost and test just the ajax request with breakpoints.Thanks for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `WebMethod` attribute and make the method `static`:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Testing()
{
    return "asdlasldalsdl";
}
```

You can also remove `data` from the ajax call, or remove the quotes.

Comment: Still doesn't work.I don't get it the code seems flawless but the ajax part is like not executed at all.Could it be something wrong with the default VS Studio Asp.net C# Web application template ?

Comment: Have you opened the browser tools and checked the console for errors?

Comment: thank you for the suggestion,i totally forgot about chrome debugging console and i found out that the call was not found , i had to specify the full url , instead of url: "mysqlcall.aspx/Testing",  i had to use url: "http://mywebsite/mysqlcall.aspx/Testing",

Comment: That's unusual. Do you have a `ScriptManager` on the page? I *think* if you add one like this `<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">`, then you won't have to do that.

Comment: no i dont have ScriptManager on the page. The strange part was it that it was looking for the mysqlcall.aspx page here "h*ttp:///mywebsite.com/results/mysqlcall.apsx" 
results.aspx is the webpage that contains the ajax script and makes the call.I'm happy that atleast now is working but still not optimal solution since it will have delay from the domain resolver.

Comment: That's pretty important to know. You can probably just do it with `results/mysqlcall.aspx/Testing` or with initial slash `/results/mysqlcall.aspx/Testing`. It's not a directory call, it's a `url` call so it has to know where to go on the site.

Comment: Although I can't really tell from your desc where the results page is. Start from the root with a slash and proceed to the correct directory and file.

Comment: Oh sorry i didn't specify , results.aspx and mysqlcall are in same folder.Results.aspx is routed to my website like mywebsite.com/results/ , and the mysqlcall.aspx is not so its mywebsite.com/mysqlcall.aspx/ .
maybe /wwwroot/mysqlcall.aspx would do it ? i'll try it.

Comment: Start with only a slash; you don't need any 'www' stuff. `/ = root`. Try `url: "/mysqlcall.aspx/Testing"`. This will get you out of the current directory and back to the root (everything at the `mywebsite.com/` level), and it will find `mysqlcall.aspx`.

Comment: Working as intended now ! :) it works both with "/" and "../" as a start.Thank you for you time and suggestions.